# How to translate px scale in Figma to actual screen size when developing a website

Tags: wordpress, web, figma

I have a website designed using Figma. Now I would like to develop a website in Wordpress using Elementor plugin based on the Figma design. Designing using Elementor is ok.

However, the design is based on 1920 width wide screen and I am developing the website on smaller desktop (say 1440 wide).

Now, everything looks big (icons, padding, width, height, etc...) on the screen I developed because I am following the px scale according to Figma design.

Is there a way that I can convert to equivalent of scale in Figma. I would like to ask for help from experience developers who knows this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While your Figma frame can be 1920px in width, it's recommended your actual content is set at 1366px. The rest can be left as white space.

That's it, there's no pixel ratio you have to worry about. Yes Figma will not be 100% as HTML/CSS, but the width/height px values are the same.

So start tightening everything to fit in 1366px in width and you're set.